# PHP Profile Image upload with progress bar and preview like Facebook

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, progress-bar, image-upload

I want to upload a profile image with a progress bar and, after uploading the image, it should show the preview of the image like on Facebook. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to show upload progress your options;

- PHP 5.4 (http://php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php)
- PHP 5.4< + Some module (APC, PECL)
- PHP + Swf (E.g. http://www.uploadify.com/)

And javascript. If you Google "php upload progress" you can find a lot of example to all of them.

Answer (score 1):

I hate facebook so i don't know what they do...

But Here is a nice DEMO: [click upload](http://www.saaraan.com/assets/ajax-image-upload-progressbar/)

Here is the Source-Code: [have fun](http://www.saaraan.com/2012/05/ajax-image-upload-with-progressbar-with-jquery-and-php)

Comment: thanks for reply, i checked this but it is not working, after progress bar completes, image does not appear.

Comment: i used it before and it worked... upload your code mybe you are missing something.